# Как сделать расположение блоков на волнистой линии?

Tags: jquery, css, вёрстка

Имеется линия в виде волны, на которой нужно расположить небольшие маркеры, количество маркеров может быть разное, но нужно, чтобы между этими маркерами было одинаковое расстояние.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут нужно использовать svg?

**P.S.**
а также как правильно создать саму линию в виде волны?
допустим линия будет в картинке img, как тогда расположить динамически маркеры на одинаковом расстоянии друг от друга?

Comment: А как описана/создана эта "линия в форме волны"?

Comment: @MBo, ещё не создана, это также хотелось бы уточнить

Comment: @MBo, на svg конечно проще это всё сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи есть три пути: dom елементы, svg и canvas. Последний во многом не удобен. Если взять, что линия - это синусоида и косинусоида, то берем и делаем через dom, так как можно легко рассчитать положение точек. Если линия свободная, то тут уже svg. 
Я пошел на условие о синусоиде (линия в вопросе, очень сильно ее напоминает). 
Решение на ванильном js через dom c адаптивностью:

```js
const dotsCont = document.getElementById('dots'); // контейнер для точек
let w = parseInt(getComputedStyle(dotsCont).width); // ширина контейнера
const h = 100; // высота контейнера
const r = 7; // радиус черных точек
let dotsNum = w / 15; // количество точек (пропорционально ширине)
const places = ['Воронеж', 'Москва', 'Владимир', 'Белгород']; // список мест
render(); // запуск 
window.addEventListener('resize', function() { // отлов изменений ширины окна и ререндер точек с новыми параметрами
  w = parseInt(getComputedStyle(dotsCont).width);
  dotsNum = w / 15;
  render();
});

function render() {
  dotsCont.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < dotsNum; i++) { // расставляем черные точки 
    dotsCont.innerHTML += '<div class="dots-item"></div>'
    const el = dotsCont.getElementsByClassName('dots-item')[i];
    const x = w / dotsNum * (i + 0.5);
    el.style.left = x + 'px';
    // формула высоты - 
    // 1) Расчитываем синус из -x (чтобы перевернуть волну) деленному на ширину(для создания гребней) умноженному на произвольное число( от него зависит число гребней)
    // 2) растягиваем точку по высоте элемента
    // 3) опускаем точку, чтобы она не вылезла за элемент
    // 4) поднимаем на радиус, чтобы желтая точка полностью перекрывала черную
    el.style.top = h / 2 * Math.sin(-x / w * 10) + h / 2 + r + 'px';
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) { // расставляем желтые точки 
    dotsCont.innerHTML += '<div class="dots-item dots-item__main" data-place=' + places[i] + '></div>'
    const item = dotsCont.getElementsByClassName('dots-item__main')[i];
    const x = w / places.length * (i + 0.5);
    item.style.left = x + 'px';
    item.style.top = h / 2 * Math.sin(-x / w * 10) + h / 2 + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#dots {
  position: relative;
}

.dots-item {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.dots-item__main {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #febf27;
}

.dots-item__main::before {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: -5px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/h2JJJJ/google_309740_960_720.png');
  background-size: cover;
}

.dots-item__main::after {
  content: attr(data-place);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots" id="dots">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daniel217/dpLkqjeo/)

Answer (score 3):

В JS задаете позицию по горизонтали и через функцию синуса или косинуса высчитываете позицию по вертикали.

```
const $points = $('.point');

for (var i = 0; i < $points.length; i++) {
  const p = $points[i];

  // здесь задается расстояние между маркерами по-горизонтали
  const x = i * 50;
  p.style.left = x + 'px';

  // здесь высота через функцию синуса
  // 35 - амплитуда, 2.5 - период, 50 - сдвиг относительно верхнего края
  const y = 35 * Math.sin(2.5 * x) + 50;
  p.style.top = y + 'px';
}
```

[Пример на CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGgJWq)

Comment: это рисуется линия, благодарю за решение. А подскажите, как теперь равномерно расположить маркеры на этой линии, маркеров может быть разное количество?

Comment: Принцип тот же, выставляете x и вычисляете y. Вообще мой пример и показывает, как маркеры расставить. Он не очень удобен для линии, т.к. в html придётся наплодить слишком много точек. Линию лучше полностью в  коде сгенерировать. Либо использовать img для линии, а параметры для маркеров подогнать под линию.

Answer (score 3):

Вот собственно `SVG` смотреться одинаково будет что в яблоках и где угодно

я разумеется cделал все маркеры не те что требуются ...но поверьте это Просто исправить

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800.667 133.888"><path d="M.623 74.6S122.866 29.52 185.83 34.534c71.182 5.67 128.168 77.085 199.572 77.863 75.646.825 137.727-72.373 213.178-77.863C664.037 29.772 791.35 74.6 791.35 74.6" fill="none" stroke="#0b0" stroke-width="3.6" stroke-dasharray="3.6,28.8" stroke-dashoffset="36"/><g transform="matrix(.43228 0 0 .43228 558.666 83.746)" fill="#fff"><path d="M-299.035-28.417A27.025 27.025 0 0 0-326.06-1.39a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 1.901 9.937l-.23.212.613.642a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.81 13.42l10.955 11.477 12.033-11.066a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.626-11.61l1.313-1.208-.48-.502a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 2.51-11.302 27.025 27.025 0 0 0-27.026-27.026z" stroke="#0b0" stroke-width="1.0001124" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse ry="11.717" rx="12.662" cy="-1.959" cx="-299.034" stroke="#0b0" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.43228 0 0 .43228 220.896 24.278)" fill="#fff"><path d="M-299.035-28.417A27.025 27.025 0 0 0-326.06-1.39a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 1.901 9.937l-.23.212.613.642a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.81 13.42l10.955 11.477 12.033-11.066a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.626-11.61l1.313-1.208-.48-.502a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 2.51-11.302 27.025 27.025 0 0 0-27.026-27.026z" stroke="#0b0" stroke-width="1.0001124" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-299.034" cy="-1.959" rx="12.662" ry="11.717" stroke="#0b0" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.43228 0 0 .43228 284.534 12.5)" fill="#fff"><path d="M-299.035-28.417A27.025 27.025 0 0 0-326.06-1.39a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 1.901 9.937l-.23.212.613.642a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.81 13.42l10.955 11.477 12.033-11.066a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.626-11.61l1.313-1.208-.48-.502a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 2.51-11.302 27.025 27.025 0 0 0-27.026-27.026z" stroke="#0b0" stroke-width="1.0001124" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-299.034" cy="-1.959" rx="12.662" ry="11.717" stroke="#0b0" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.43228 0 0 .43228 377.837 32.312)" fill="#fff"><path d="M-299.035-28.417A27.025 27.025 0 0 0-326.06-1.39a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 1.901 9.937l-.23.212.613.642a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.81 13.42l10.955 11.477 12.033-11.066a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.626-11.61l1.313-1.208-.48-.502a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 2.51-11.302 27.025 27.025 0 0 0-27.026-27.026z" stroke="#0b0" stroke-width="1.0001124" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-299.034" cy="-1.959" rx="12.662" ry="11.717" stroke="#0b0" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.43228 0 0 .43228 494.542 87.18)" fill="#fff"><path d="M-299.035-28.417A27.025 27.025 0 0 0-326.06-1.39a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 1.901 9.937l-.23.212.613.642a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.81 13.42l10.955 11.477 12.033-11.066a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.626-11.61l1.313-1.208-.48-.502a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 2.51-11.302 27.025 27.025 0 0 0-27.026-27.026z" stroke="#0b0" stroke-width="1.0001124" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-299.034" cy="-1.959" rx="12.662" ry="11.717" stroke="#0b0" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.43228 0 0 .43228 434.402 63.228)" fill="#fff"><path d="M-299.035-28.417A27.025 27.025 0 0 0-326.06-1.39a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 1.901 9.937l-.23.212.613.642a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.81 13.42l10.955 11.477 12.033-11.066a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.626-11.61l1.313-1.208-.48-.502a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 2.51-11.302 27.025 27.025 0 0 0-27.026-27.026z" stroke="#0b0" stroke-width="1.0001124" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse ry="11.717" rx="12.662" cy="-1.959" cx="-299.034" stroke="#0b0" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.43228 0 0 .43228 833.414 26.296)"><path d="M-299.035-28.417A27.025 27.025 0 0 0-326.06-1.39a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 1.901 9.937l-.23.212.613.642a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.81 13.42l10.955 11.477 12.033-11.066a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.626-11.61l1.313-1.208-.48-.502a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 2.51-11.302 27.025 27.025 0 0 0-27.026-27.026z" fill="none" stroke="#0b0" stroke-width="1.0001124" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-299.034" cy="-1.959" rx="12.662" ry="11.717" fill="#fff" stroke="#0b0" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.43228 0 0 .43228 769.808 13.38)" fill="#fff"><path d="M-299.035-28.417A27.025 27.025 0 0 0-326.06-1.39a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 1.901 9.937l-.23.212.613.642a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.81 13.42l10.955 11.477 12.033-11.066a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.626-11.61l1.313-1.208-.48-.502a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 2.51-11.302 27.025 27.025 0 0 0-27.026-27.026z" stroke="#0b0" stroke-width="1.0001124" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-299.034" cy="-1.959" rx="12.662" ry="11.717" stroke="#0b0" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.43228 0 0 .43228 616.808 55.873)" fill="#fff"><path d="M-299.035-28.417A27.025 27.025 0 0 0-326.06-1.39a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 1.901 9.937l-.23.212.613.642a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.81 13.42l10.955 11.477 12.033-11.066a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.626-11.61l1.313-1.208-.48-.502a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 2.51-11.302 27.025 27.025 0 0 0-27.026-27.026z" stroke="#0b0" stroke-width="1.0001124" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-299.034" cy="-1.959" rx="12.662" ry="11.717" stroke="#0b0" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.43228 0 0 .43228 895.098 44.483)" fill="#fff"><path d="M-299.035-28.417A27.025 27.025 0 0 0-326.06-1.39a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 1.901 9.937l-.23.212.613.642a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.81 13.42l10.955 11.477 12.033-11.066a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.626-11.61l1.313-1.208-.48-.502a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 2.51-11.302 27.025 27.025 0 0 0-27.026-27.026z" stroke="#0b0" stroke-width="1.0001124" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse ry="11.717" rx="12.662" cy="-1.959" cx="-299.034" stroke="#0b0" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.43228 0 0 .43228 705.288 15.51)" fill="#fff"><path d="M-299.035-28.417A27.025 27.025 0 0 0-326.06-1.39a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 1.901 9.937l-.23.212.613.642a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.81 13.42l10.955 11.477 12.033-11.066a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 12.626-11.61l1.313-1.208-.48-.502a27.025 27.025 0 0 0 2.51-11.302 27.025 27.025 0 0 0-27.026-27.026z" stroke="#0b0" stroke-width="1.0001124" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-299.034" cy="-1.959" rx="12.662" ry="11.717" stroke="#0b0" stroke-dashoffset="113.393" stroke-opacity=".992" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><path d="M.623 74.6S122.866 29.52 185.83 34.534c71.182 5.67 128.168 77.085 199.572 77.863 75.646.825 137.727-72.373 213.178-77.863C664.037 29.772 791.35 74.6 791.35 74.6" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".5" stroke-dashoffset="30"/><path d="M61.595 67.232h20.19c7.903-7.297 11.787-3.877 15.501 0h19.917V83.34H61.595z" fill="#e6e6e6" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".603" stroke-dashoffset="36" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text y="313.831" x="-389.028" style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke-width=".265" transform="translate(456.38 -234.906)"><tspan y="313.831" x="-389.028">moskow</tspan></text><path d="M120.907 50.901h24.46c9.576-5.959 14.282-3.165 18.781 0h24.13v13.156h-67.37z" fill="#e6e6e6" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".6" stroke-dashoffset="36" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text y="315.418" x="-183.765" style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke-width=".265" transform="translate(312.57 -254.191)"><tspan y="315.418" x="-183.765">novgorod</tspan></text><path d="M215.006 65.376h24.46c9.576-5.96 14.282-3.166 18.781 0h24.13V78.53h-67.37z" fill="#e6e6e6" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".6" stroke-dashoffset="36" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text y="296.54" x="-193.394" style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke-width=".265" transform="translate(423.773 -221.542)"><tspan y="296.54" x="-193.394">kaluga</tspan></text><path d="M270.064 94.775h24.46c9.575-5.959 14.281-3.165 18.78 0h24.13v13.156h-67.37z" fill="#e6e6e6" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".6" stroke-dashoffset="36" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text y="314.365" x="-172.005" style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke-width=".265" transform="translate(455.311 -208.714)"><tspan y="314.365" x="-172.005">lipetsk</tspan></text><path d="M331.536 120.433h24.46c9.575-5.959 14.281-3.165 18.78 0h24.13v13.155h-67.37z" fill="#e6e6e6" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".6" stroke-dashoffset="36" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text y="281.758" x="-57.079" style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke-width=".265" transform="translate(413.617 -150.983)"><tspan y="281.758" x="-57.079">tula</tspan></text><path d="M395.732 115.142h24.46c9.575-5.96 14.281-3.166 18.78 0h24.13v13.155h-67.37z" fill="#e6e6e6" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".6" stroke-dashoffset="36" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text y="333.571" x="-39.44" style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke-width=".265" transform="translate(447.879 -209.194)"><tspan y="333.571" x="-39.44">ryasan</tspan></text><g><path d="M453.934 88.404h24.46c9.576-5.96 14.282-3.166 18.781 0h24.13v13.155h-67.37z" fill="#e6e6e6" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".6" stroke-dashoffset="36" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text y="320.498" x="-6.236" style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke-width=".265" transform="translate(477.751 -222.569)"><tspan y="320.498" x="-6.236">tanbov</tspan></text></g><g><path d="M542.7 48.26h24.46c9.576-5.96 14.282-3.166 18.781 0h24.13v13.155h-67.37z" fill="#e6e6e6" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".6" stroke-dashoffset="36" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text y="300.435" x="95.788" style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke-width=".265" transform="translate(462.282 -242.4)"><tspan y="300.435" x="95.788">pensa</tspan></text></g><g><path d="M606.367 46.672h24.46c9.575-5.959 14.282-3.165 18.78 0h24.13v13.155h-67.37z" fill="#e6e6e6" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".6" stroke-dashoffset="36" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text y="303.118" x="235.254" style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke-width=".265" transform="translate(387.503 -246.66)"><tspan y="303.118" x="235.254">kazan</tspan></text></g><g><path d="M670.034 59.298h24.46c9.575-5.959 14.282-3.165 18.78 0h24.13v13.155h-67.37z" fill="#e6e6e6" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".6" stroke-dashoffset="36" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text y="300.97" x="331.541" style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke-width=".265" transform="translate(349.073 -232.43)"><tspan y="300.97" x="331.541">arsamas</tspan></text></g><g><path d="M732.996 76.665h24.46c9.576-5.959 14.282-3.165 18.781 0h24.13v13.156h-67.371z" fill="#e6e6e6" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".6" stroke-dashoffset="36" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><text y="250.467" x="402.724" style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" stroke-width=".265" transform="translate(344.148 -163.748)"><tspan y="250.467" x="402.724">saransk</tspan></text></g></svg>
```

второй вариант

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 747.503 159.605"><g transform="translate(376.506 -23.505)"><path d="M-369.66 120.107s67.093-41.348 104.322-40.065c31.943 1.1 56.81 29.773 86.934 40.456 50.198 17.802 101.741 40.741 154.971 38.919 41.312-1.415 78.776-25.1 117.927-38.362 38.968-13.2 75.31-39.291 116.417-41.013 54.897-2.3 159.506 41.577 159.506 41.577" fill="none" stroke="#00e800" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="18,18"/><circle cx="324.304" cy="103.703" r="6.804" fill="#ff2a2a" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><circle r="6.804" cy="122.375" cx="-170.089" fill="#ff2a2a" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><circle cx="-227.542" cy="94.329" r="6.804" fill="#ff2a2a" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><circle r="6.804" cy="87.601" cx="-298.601" fill="#ff2a2a" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><circle r="6.804" cy="148.077" cx="24.946" fill="#ff2a2a" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><circle cx="-40.821" cy="159.417" r="6.804" fill="#ff2a2a" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><circle r="6.804" cy="148.304" cx="-98.803" fill="#ff2a2a" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><circle r="6.804" cy="83.821" cx="254.756" fill="#ff2a2a" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><circle cx="186.72" cy="81.856" r="6.804" fill="#ff2a2a" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><circle r="6.804" cy="106.5" cx="127.756" fill="#ff2a2a" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><circle cx="-353.786" cy="111.792" r="6.804" fill="#ff2a2a" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><circle r="6.804" cy="128.423" cx="75.822" fill="#ff2a2a" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><g transform="matrix(.618 0 0 .6221 -249.878 -65.591)" fill="none" stroke="#00e800"><path d="M-169.711 190.41a32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128 27.971 32.128 27.97 0 0 0 4.155 13.69l-.383.405 1.9 1.722a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 7.22 6.544l19.936 18.066 15.362-16.243a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 14.294-15.114l1.174-1.243-.56-.507a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 1.158-7.32 32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128-27.97z" stroke-width="3.00007262" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse ry="16.631" rx="19.655" cy="218.91" cx="-170.014" stroke-width="3" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.618 0 0 .6221 -194.694 -87.136)" fill="none" stroke="#00e800"><path d="M-169.711 190.41a32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128 27.971 32.128 27.97 0 0 0 4.155 13.69l-.383.405 1.9 1.722a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 7.22 6.544l19.936 18.066 15.362-16.243a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 14.294-15.114l1.174-1.243-.56-.507a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 1.158-7.32 32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128-27.97z" stroke-width="3.00007262" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-170.014" cy="218.91" rx="19.655" ry="16.631" stroke-width="3" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.618 0 0 .6221 -123.18 -84.112)" fill="none" stroke="#00e800"><path d="M-169.711 190.41a32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128 27.971 32.128 27.97 0 0 0 4.155 13.69l-.383.405 1.9 1.722a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 7.22 6.544l19.936 18.066 15.362-16.243a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 14.294-15.114l1.174-1.243-.56-.507a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 1.158-7.32 32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128-27.97z" stroke-width="3.00007262" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse ry="16.631" rx="19.655" cy="218.91" cx="-170.014" stroke-width="3" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.618 0 0 .6221 -64.065 -53.798)" fill="none" stroke="#00e800"><path d="M-169.711 190.41a32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128 27.971 32.128 27.97 0 0 0 4.155 13.69l-.383.405 1.9 1.722a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 7.22 6.544l19.936 18.066 15.362-16.243a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 14.294-15.114l1.174-1.243-.56-.507a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 1.158-7.32 32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128-27.97z" stroke-width="3.00007262" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-170.014" cy="218.91" rx="19.655" ry="16.631" stroke-width="3" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.618 0 0 .6221 5.86 -29.003)" fill="none" stroke="#00e800"><path d="M-169.711 190.41a32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128 27.971 32.128 27.97 0 0 0 4.155 13.69l-.383.405 1.9 1.722a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 7.22 6.544l19.936 18.066 15.362-16.243a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 14.294-15.114l1.174-1.243-.56-.507a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 1.158-7.32 32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128-27.97z" stroke-width="3.00007262" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse ry="16.631" rx="19.655" cy="218.91" cx="-170.014" stroke-width="3" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.618 0 0 .6221 64.069 -17.134)" fill="none" stroke="#00e800"><path d="M-169.711 190.41a32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128 27.971 32.128 27.97 0 0 0 4.155 13.69l-.383.405 1.9 1.722a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 7.22 6.544l19.936 18.066 15.362-16.243a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 14.294-15.114l1.174-1.243-.56-.507a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 1.158-7.32 32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128-27.97z" stroke-width="3.00007262" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-170.014" cy="218.91" rx="19.655" ry="16.631" stroke-width="3" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.618 0 0 .6221 128.551 -26.055)" fill="none" stroke="#00e800"><path d="M-169.711 190.41a32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128 27.971 32.128 27.97 0 0 0 4.155 13.69l-.383.405 1.9 1.722a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 7.22 6.544l19.936 18.066 15.362-16.243a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 14.294-15.114l1.174-1.243-.56-.507a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 1.158-7.32 32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128-27.97z" stroke-width="3.00007262" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse ry="16.631" rx="19.655" cy="218.91" cx="-170.014" stroke-width="3" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.618 0 0 .6221 177.915 -47.146)" fill="none" stroke="#00e800"><path d="M-169.711 190.41a32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128 27.971 32.128 27.97 0 0 0 4.155 13.69l-.383.405 1.9 1.722a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 7.22 6.544l19.936 18.066 15.362-16.243a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 14.294-15.114l1.174-1.243-.56-.507a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 1.158-7.32 32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128-27.97z" stroke-width="3.00007262" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-170.014" cy="218.91" rx="19.655" ry="16.631" stroke-width="3" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.618 0 0 .6221 230.907 -70.505)" fill="none" stroke="#00e800"><path d="M-169.711 190.41a32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128 27.971 32.128 27.97 0 0 0 4.155 13.69l-.383.405 1.9 1.722a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 7.22 6.544l19.936 18.066 15.362-16.243a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 14.294-15.114l1.174-1.243-.56-.507a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 1.158-7.32 32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128-27.97z" stroke-width="3.00007262" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse ry="16.631" rx="19.655" cy="218.91" cx="-170.014" stroke-width="3" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.618 0 0 .6221 289.72 -94.015)" fill="none" stroke="#00e800"><path d="M-169.711 190.41a32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128 27.971 32.128 27.97 0 0 0 4.155 13.69l-.383.405 1.9 1.722a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 7.22 6.544l19.936 18.066 15.362-16.243a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 14.294-15.114l1.174-1.243-.56-.507a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 1.158-7.32 32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128-27.97z" stroke-width="3.00007262" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-170.014" cy="218.91" rx="19.655" ry="16.631" stroke-width="3" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.618 0 0 .6221 358.663 -93.864)" fill="none" stroke="#00e800"><path d="M-169.711 190.41a32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128 27.971 32.128 27.97 0 0 0 4.155 13.69l-.383.405 1.9 1.722a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 7.22 6.544l19.936 18.066 15.362-16.243a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 14.294-15.114l1.174-1.243-.56-.507a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 1.158-7.32 32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128-27.97z" stroke-width="3.00007262" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse ry="16.631" rx="19.655" cy="218.91" cx="-170.014" stroke-width="3" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><g transform="matrix(.618 0 0 .6221 428.438 -73.755)" fill="none" stroke="#00e800"><path d="M-169.711 190.41a32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128 27.971 32.128 27.97 0 0 0 4.155 13.69l-.383.405 1.9 1.722a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 7.22 6.544l19.936 18.066 15.362-16.243a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 14.294-15.114l1.174-1.243-.56-.507a32.128 27.97 0 0 0 1.158-7.32 32.128 27.97 0 0 0-32.128-27.97z" stroke-width="3.00007262" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/><ellipse cx="-170.014" cy="218.91" rx="19.655" ry="16.631" stroke-width="3" paint-order="stroke fill markers"/></g><text style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="-376.767" y="137.343" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" stroke-width=".265"><tspan x="-376.767" y="137.343">gordod1</tspan></text><text style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="-317.273" y="111.036" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" stroke-width=".265"><tspan x="-317.273" y="111.036">gorod2</tspan></text><text style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="-248.406" y="116.176" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" stroke-width=".265"><tspan x="-248.406" y="116.176">gorod3</tspan></text><text style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="-190.727" y="141.576" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" stroke-width=".265"><tspan x="-190.727" y="141.576">gorod4</tspan></text><text style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="-118.76" y="166.296" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" stroke-width=".265"><tspan x="-118.76" y="166.296">gorod5</tspan></text><text style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="-60.476" y="180.357" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" stroke-width=".265"><tspan x="-60.476" y="180.357">gorod6</tspan></text><text style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="6.274" y="167.43" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" stroke-width=".265"><tspan x="6.274" y="167.43">gorod7</tspan></text><text style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="56.47" y="150.345" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" stroke-width=".265"><tspan x="56.47" y="150.345">gorod8</tspan></text><text style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="108.101" y="126.079" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" stroke-width=".265"><tspan x="108.101" y="126.079">gorod9</tspan></text><text style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="164.722" y="104.005" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" stroke-width=".265"><tspan x="164.722" y="104.005">gorod10</tspan></text><text style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="233.211" y="103.098" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" stroke-width=".265"><tspan x="233.211" y="103.098">gorod11</tspan></text><text style="line-height:6.61458302px;-inkscape-font-specification:Georgia" x="301.322" y="124.492" font-weight="400" font-size="12.7" font-family="Georgia" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" stroke-width=".265"><tspan x="301.322" y="124.492">gorod12</tspan></text></g></svg>
```

Comment: полоску пунктиром, задача чуть-чуть посложнее=))

Comment: @Arthur на скрине точки а не пунктир

Comment: пунктирные точки)))

Comment: @Arthur  а вот теперь я маркеры вкрутил

Comment: Нормально. Этот вопрос похож на один из ранее существующих